# Notation for mixed partial derivatives

Tags: notation, partial-derivative

If $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$, what does $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\, \partial y}$$ mean?
Does it mean $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$ or $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)$?

(I know that most of the time due to Schwarz theorem it is irrelevant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of convention see e.g. [here](https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/partialdifferentiation/) and [here](http://citadel.sjfc.edu/faculty/kgreen/vector/block2/pder/node5.html). So you should look at your lecture notes to use the definition proposed there.

In any case, if $f$ is **twice continuously differentiable**, then $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\!\!\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\!\!\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)$$

Comment: Your link in "By definition" says the opposite

Comment: @Matteo you are right, it seems to be a matter of convention.

Comment: @Surb although I agree with you that there seem to be two convention coexisting, I have to point out that the two link you provide have the same definition of $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\, \partial y}:= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\!\!\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$. I prefer this convention as the apply of the derivative follows the order of lecture.

Comment: @ThomasProduit Ok, let me change the link.

Comment: @Surb I don't want to be rude but my comment applies for those links too...

Comment: @ThomasProduit It's not rude at all. Thank you for pointing out this mixing between links (again)... I think now it is ok.