# Choosing the definition of $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, notation, definition, convention

Today, I answered [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1136413/notation-for-mixed-partial-derivatives/1136415#1136415) and discovered that the definition of $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}$ is a matter of convention.

For example this [.edu link](http://citadel.sjfc.edu/faculty/kgreen/vector/block2/pder/node5.html) and this other [.edu link](http://math.etsu.edu/multicalc/prealpha/Chap2/Chap2-3/printversion.pdf) use the convention
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}:=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) \qquad \qquad (1)$$

However, [this wikipedia article](http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Second-order_mixed_partial_derivative#Definition), this [.edu link](https://math.okstate.edu/people/binegar/4013-U98/4013-l10.pdf) and this other [.edu link](https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/partialdifferentiation/) use the convention

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) \qquad \qquad (2)$$

Since apparently the definition has not been fixed yet, I can imagine that both definitions has advantages/disadvantages depending on the context they are used. However, I can't find any of these situation.

> **Question:** What are the pros and cons of each definition?

**EDIT:** At the time I write this edit, it seems that even in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) about partial derivatives, there is a "contradiction", [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#Notation) definition $(1)$ is used but [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#Higher_order_partial_derivatives) they use definition $(2)$...

Comment: I don't see the first edu link saying (1) holds either. In fact, I've never seen anywhere the definition used in (1). I've heard about it, but I've never seen it.

Comment: @GitGud Your wrong: The first edu link says indeed (1) holds... I personally am also for the interpretation explained by Arthur as it is very comfortable to apply the derivative in the order of lecture

Comment: @GitGud In the first edu link they say that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$ can be rewritten as $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}$

Comment: @ThomasProduit Technically I'm not wrong because I didn't say (1) isn't in the first edu link, I said I don't see it. I find the page hard to read, it looks horrible, so I didn't check everything, but rather glanced at it. In a second glance I still can't find. Where exactly are they using (1)? I also prefer (2), but note that Arthur deleted his comment.

Comment: @GitGud Directly at the beginning they compare both notations. They say the first list of derivatives can rewritten (respectively) as the second list

Comment: @Surb I see now, I missed the 'respectively'.

Comment: By the way, search for "second order derivatives .edu" on google shows many examples for both notations.

Comment: I'll just add a pro for (2) here in the comments since I really don't know of any cons for (2) or any pros for (1). The second option allows for a natural condensation of the notation. Similarly, $f_{xy}$should be $\left(f_x\right)_y$. A con for (1) is that it counters this very natural approach used in (2).

Comment: @GitGud Please have a look at my edit to get why I was confused about your comment on the wikipedia article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We all know that mixed derivatives are equal under very mild hypotheses, and whenever these hyptheses are unquestionably fulfilled nobody cares wether we should write ${\partial^2 f\over \partial x\partial y}$ or ${\partial^2 f\over \partial y\partial x}$.

As soon as there is only a hint of a suspicion that the order of differentiation could matter any author would precise on his first page what exactly is meant by ${\partial^2 f\over \partial x\partial y}$.

To sum it all up: This is a *very tiny* notational ambiguity left over in the sea of mathematics that should detract nobody from addressing the heart of the matter at hand.

Comment: Ok, but why would an author choose one definition instead of the other?

Comment: Some countries adhere to left-hand traffic, and others don't.